# Which flag for standard apps in PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(flag)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-package-managers

When I open the Android main menu on my Android smartphone, I get a set of apps like Youtube, Calculator, Email clients etc. No system stuff or any libraries are visible there.

To retrieve these apps programamtically, I do:

```
PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(flag: Int)
```

where I get a list of `ApplicationInfo`, which also contains alot more than mentioned installed standard apps. What flag do I have to set to get only the same apps, which I see when I swipe up on my Smartphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
val appList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0)
```

You can try this to get all user apps (and the ones your launcher shows)

You might need to add additional permissions in your manifest above Android 10 though

Edit: If you want ApplicationInfo instead of ResolveInfo in your list you can retrieve it like this:

```
appList[your_index].activityInfo.applicationInfo
```